# Casting from String to Byte. Is the CLR optimized to handle better castings when done to Int32 instead of Byte?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, compilation, clr

Is the CLR optimized to handle String casts to an Int32 better than it does for String to Byte? Normally many programmers would cast numerical values to an Int32, rather than be insanely precise.

Stupid example:

`int a = int.Parse("0");` vs `byte a = byte.Parse("0");`

Comment: Do you mean `char` instead of `string`? I.e. `'0'` instead of `"0"`? A `string` can only be _parsed_ to an `int`; not _cast_. And a `char` in .Net is UTF-16, so it's two bytes. Casting it to one byte might fail. Now the question is, does it matter one way or the other? Probably not, but feel free to [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: @Corak yeah, I meant parsing. I'll fix the code above.

Comment: Okay, I just tested casting a million random `char` (ASCII range) to `int`, `byte` and `short` with benchmarkDotNet (no affiliation) and the differences are in the realm of statistical errors. So no "optimization" detectable.

Comment: And just did something similar (a million random values in byte range converted to string and then parsed into int/byte/short) for strings and the differences are equally neglible. -- so if you _know_ the strings are actually byte values and you want to work with them as bytes, then parse them into bytes. It won't be faster or slower than parsing them into ints. Ints just give you more "room to breathe" and depending on what you do, the bytes might silently be turned into ints and back anyways.

Comment: @Corak if you'd like to answer this question, please post it properly as an answer !(not as comment)

Comment: I only provided empirical evidence. I cannot ultimately answer the question, if the CLR does have optimizations at work or not.